# How do I get to transfer an array from the server side to client side in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have the following function on the client side:

```
                //TODO: to fix
                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/home');
                socket.on('news', function (data) {
                    console.log('testing: ' + data);
                    //socket.emit('my other event', {my: 'data'});
                });
```

And the following on the server side:

```
module.exports = function(app, io) {

    app.get('/home',function(req, res){
        //res.render('profile.ejs');
    });
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('news', {
        data: 'world'
        });
};
```

The problem is that I can't seem to log the received data to the client's console. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `console.log('testing: ' , data);`

Comment: @dandavis it worked! it was my fault, please submit your answer so I accept it and thanks a bunch

Comment: place a log inside on connection function and check whether it's being connected or not

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.stringify() for printing whole data in proper formate`

```
console.log('testing: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `console.log('testing: ' + data);`, Javascript is trying to convert the object `data` to a string, by calling `toString`. This will result in the string "testing: [object Object]".

You need to either manually convert the object to a more useful string, e.g. by calling `JSON.stringify(data)`, or you can make use of the feature that `console.log` may receive multiple arguments:

`console.log('testing:', data);`

This way your console is printing the acutall object and not a string representation.